# Which is correct shape of linear regression in my model?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am designing regression network to predict the weight of a person from 10 to 100 kg. My dataset has 50 training data that is

```
Vector 1: 1024x1 corresponding to 40kg
Vector 2: 1024x1 corresponding to 20kg
Vector 3: 1024x1 corresponding to 40kg
...
Vector 50: 1024x1 corresponding to 30kg
```

Hence, my dataset size is `1024x50`, and the label size is `1x50`. If I design a simple linear regression, like `y=xW+b`, so the size of `W` and `b` will be

```
W is 1024x1
b is 1x50
```

Am I right?

This is my tensorflow code but it provide a wrong prediction

```
# Training Data
train_X = ...# shape of 1024 x 50
train_Y = ...# shape of 1x50
n_samples = 50
learning_rate = 0.0001
training_epochs = 1000
display_step = 50
# tf Graph Input
X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")
# Set model weights
W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([1024, 1], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(1, dtype = tf.float32))
# Construct a linear model
pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b)
# Mean squared error
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
# Start training
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Run the initializer
    sess.run(init)
    # Fit all training data
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        for (x, y) in zip(train_X, train_Y):
            sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={X: x, Y: y})
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if (epoch + 1) % display_step == 0:
            c = sess.run(cost, feed_dict={X: train_X, Y: train_Y})
            print("Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch + 1), "cost=", "{:.9f}".format(c), \
                  "W=", sess.run(W), "b=", sess.run(b))
    print("Optimization Finished!")
```

Comment: Your code looks reasonable; what kind of output are you getting?  Where did you get your input from?  My best guess at this point is that there is no learnable relationship between the feature vectors and the labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> W is 1024x1
>   b is 1x50
>   Am I right?

No, shape of W is correct, but b should be a scalar (1x1 matrix). In your approach you have one trainable bias per data point which makes no sense. However, in your code it is correctly set to size 1.

What is wrong is handling matrix multiplication, your model should be:

```
pred = tf.matmul(X, W) + b # you will have to transpose your train_X
```

tf.multiply is **pointwise** multiplication, not matrix multiplication.